# How can I spin in a for loop for a random but very small amount of time in c++?

Tags: c++, spinning

So I basically have the ability to capture some packets from a multicast environment and I save them to file and then I multicast them out to applications which expect multicast data. I do this for simulation purposes. It's a relatively simple tool, and it has served me well when replaying 10 or even 50K packets to an application running in gdb. My replay loop looks like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < packets_.size(); ++i)
    publisher_.publish(packets_[i].buf_, packets_[i].len_);
```

and the problem is that when packets_.size() is around 100-200K (I would never need to do more than that) I seem to experience packet loss when somebody is listening. I am guessing this is because they are replayed in one continuous burst. If I tried things like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < packets_.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i % Y == 0) usleep(X);
    publisher_.publish(packets_[i].buf_, packets_[i].len_);
}
```

for varying amounts in `Y` and `X` (like 1000/1000 and many other combos) but this doesn't work very well. My guess was that I could patch this up if I could busy chew cycles on every iteration for a very small amount of time. Busy chew because I don't want to yield to other processes and thus take longer than expected, but a very small amount, not even a millisecond because that would entail 200 seconds of waiting to multicast out the packets. Repeated calls in a loop to a sleep function seem to yield and slow me down considerably, which is why I was wondering what a simple way to spin for maybe a quarter, fifth, half, or so of a millisecond (roughly) be?

Or if there would be a better and simple way to patch this for this use case?

Comment: can you elaborate your question a bit more?
What do you mean by `usleep` doesnt work?

Comment: @BeyondSora he means sleep for microseconds, @ OP What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to consume or release the CPU during this pause? I assume by "busy work" you mean you want to chew up cycles. Please clarify.

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong with usleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function below keeps system 'busy' for some unspecified time:

```
static long slow( volatile long l ) {
   while ( l-- > 0 )  ;
   return l ;
}
```

Take some number, let's say 1000, and then run `slow( N )` and at the same time count how long did it take taking `clock_t t = clock()` before and after call. Increase N, and repeat the same opertion until you find the number N that will keep the loop busy for 1 second. You will have now a function and a number that will keep the system busy for one second.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Note: `l` should be made `volatile`, or the compiler might optimize the `while` into an assignment (and optimize that out too, if it is not consumed).

Comment: Note that if you must do this, then in order for it to work you have to choose `N` *at runtime*. And then still don't do it. People who used busy loops for timing wrote a whole bunch of games that ran way too fast to play on the next generation of PCs. This resulted in "turbo" buttons whose purpose was to slow the CPU down so you could use your programs. Do not repeat history :-)

Comment: Yup. I remember when a game from ZX Spectrum was moved to the new 128 one. There was a game where monkeys were throwing pinaples from threes and the player had to avoid these fruits. On ZX it was a nice old-type game. On 128 you barely moved and you were under a pile of pinaples :-D

Comment: And I guess clock speeds *have* stalled for the past few years, so the questioner might be able to use a busy loop without the next computer burying those multicast receivers under another pile of pineapples.

Comment: This is nice, I am currently calling the above function where the argument I pass to slow is the size of the array packet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a busy wait loop:

```
#include <chrono>

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
while(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start < std::chrono::nanoseconds(500))
    ;
```

The actual minimum time you can wait depends on the resolution of your implementation's high_resolution_clock. VS2012 unfortunately [does not have](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/c-chrono-headers-high-resolution-clock-does-not-have-high-resolution) a decent implementation yet. boost::chrono can also be used and it is much better.

If you're looking for the time to actually be random you can use the `<random>` library:

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 eng;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(200,800);

auto delay = std::chrono::nanoseconds(dist(eng));
```

Here's the C++11 version of usleep, for when you do want to give up the CPU.

```
#include <thread>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(500));
```

Comment: whoa what is std::mt19937? Nice had never seen that before. And yes I don't want to give up the CPU if possible.

Comment: @PalaceChan C++11 got a vastly improved random number library including many different engines and distributions. mt19937 is part of that. I've updated my answer to focus on the busy-wait loop since that will not deliberately give up the CPU.